# How to create Cordova Blackberry (Hybrid) application

Tags: javascript, cordova, blackberry-10

I have so many tried to create hybrid app using cordova CLI. But I have not got any success till yet.I have created Android application using cordova CLI.

We face following issue while setup Blackberry for Hybrid app development:

1. We tried  BlackBerry Momentics IDE for hybrid application.
2. We tried  WebWork SDK  for hybrid application, created application structure but not able to import  in IDE & not able to adding plugin in project.While building replace custom WWW folder with default one.
3. We tried IBM work light Integration,created application structure but not able to adding plugin and run app.

Answer (score 0):

Take your existing Android app and run

```
cordova platform add blackberry10
```

then

```
cordova build --release blackberry10
```

Keep in mind that not all of your plugins may be compatible with BB10.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I have used WebWork tool.Main problem I am facing that which IDE use to import this project and how to add plugin in future using cordova CLI.Please give me screen shot.

Comment: There is no IDE. An IDE is only required for building iOS apps. Open the app source files in www/ with any editor you like. I use Sublime Text. To add plugins, use the CLI as documented here: (http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface). "cordova plugin add com.myplugin.name". I strongly suggest reading that page, and perhaps splitting your many questions into many SO questions to keep things properly organized.